# How could I implement weather forecast based on geolocation using Open Weather Map?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website there are 2 buttons and a search bar. If you enter a city name there and press one of the 2 buttons, you' ll get the forecast of that city. If you press the other one, you'll get the coordinates of your position. I just want to remove the coordinates and get the weather forecast even when you press the geolocation button. I've tried a lot, but I'm not good enough.
I need Open Weather Map APIs to be used.
Thanks to all those who will help me.
I attach al the JS code below.

```
function getWeather () {
$('.weatherResponse').html('');
var cityName = $('#cityName').val();
var apiCall=
'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName +
'&appid=02b664040367b84ac7ae1334618923fd'
;
$.getJSON(apiCall, weatherCallback);
function weatherCallback(weatherData) {
  var cityName = weatherData.name;
  var country = weatherData.sys.country;
  var temp=
  weatherData.main.temp;
  temp = parseInt(temp) - 273;
  var description=
  weatherData.weather[0].description;
  var iconcode=
  weatherData.weather[0].icon;
  var iconurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + iconcode + "@2x.png";
  $('.weatherResponse').append("The weather in " + cityName + " " + country + " is currently " + description + " and it' s " + temp + "°");
  document.getElementById('wicon').style.display='inline';
    $('#wicon').attr('src', iconurl);
}
}
function GeoFind()
{
  var out = document.getElementById("out");
  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    out.innerHTML = "<p> Geolocation is not supported in your browser </p>";
    return;
  }
  var geo_options = {
    enableHeightAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 30000,
    timeout: 27000,
  }
  function geo_success(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    out.innerHTML = "<p> Latitude is  "+ lat +" ° <br>Longitude is  "+ long +" ° </p>";
  }
  function geo_error () {
    out.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location!";
  }
  out.innerHTML = "<p> Locating... </p>";
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
}
```

Comment: Just call the function which send forecast, on both the buttons.

Comment: just pipe the latlng from your geolocation to api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}